# how can i use a a vue component inside knockout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, knockout.js

I have a large page with a lot of knockout code and I want to use a Vue.js component for a small part of it.

I did try using controlsDescendantBindings on a tag around the component and it seems to work somewhat (I tried doing `<p data-bind=" text: name"></p>` and nothing shows) but Vue isn't working.

I think part of the problem is that it is inside a knockout `with` context.

I'm new to Vue and trying to switch over from knockout slowly, so if anyone can give me some insight into this I would really appreciate it.

(for reference, I'm using Vue through the CDN.)

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was that the block of code that the Vue component was in was being rendered conditionally by knockout. so what I did was append the component after that part of the DOM was rendered.